# Can't import layer xxx: name arp_display is not defined Python

Tags: python, network-programming, layer, scapy

I have a problem this simple code that one day stopped working and any other scapy involved code brings me a similar error(cant import layer(the layer im trying to use,arp,tcp..) and the function name)

this is the code:

```
from scapy.all import *
def arp_display(pkt):
    if pkt[ARP].op == 1: #who-has (request)
        return "Request: " + pkt[ARP].psrc + " is asking about " + pkt[ARP].pdst
    if pkt[ARP].op == 2: #is-at (response)
        return "*Response: " + pkt[ARP].hwsrc + " has address " + pkt[ARP].psrc
print sniff(prn=arp_display, filter="arp", store=0, count=1500)
```

this is the error:

> WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
>
> WARNING: can't import layer inet: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer dhcp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer dns: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer gprs: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer hsrp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer inet6: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer isakmp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer l2tp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer mgcp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer mobileip: name 'arp_display' is not
>   defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer netbios: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer ntp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer ppp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer rip: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer sebek: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer skinny: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer smb: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer snmp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer tftp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer dhcp6: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer llmnr: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer sctp: name 'arp_display' is not defined
>
> WARNING: can't import layer vrrp: name 'arp_display' is not defined

Comment: It looks to me like `arp_display` is supposed to consume a parameter, and in `sniff` you are passing it as if it is a variable. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: they are  warnings not errors, also what version of scapy?

Comment: the scapy version is scapy 2.3.0

Comment: what can I do/install to get those things to work?

Answer (score 1):

I just had that problem. I had a few python scripts on my desktop which were about DNS (dns request and dns redirection). When running those, there was a new script with the same name but with the extention pyx (I believe) that was created when running the script. The solution? I deleted the scripts and the ones that were created afterwards (dns_request.py and dns_request.pyx). When running other scripts, the Warnings were gone!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scapy\layers and open all.py
2. Add "from layer-that-you-need-to-add import *"
   ex) from inet import *

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: I think packet maybe has to use those layers. 'scapy.all' import 'layers.all' but 'layers.all' doesn't import layers in 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scapy\layers' folder. So I just import layers.